# Is there a way to nullify a bundle of static properties?

Tags: c#, static, static-members

In my mvc website I used to use static variable to stock shared variables between the requests, is there a way to "invalidate" a bundle of static variable without restart all my app, or nullifing them in their getter.

```
public static object IdsFromSomethingLocker = new object();
        public static int[] IdsFromSomething
        {
            get
            {
                if (_idsFromSomething == null)
                {
                    lock (IdsFromSomethingLocker)
                    {
                        if (_idsFromSomething == null)
                        {                            
                           _idsFromSomething = // some long loading treatment
                        }
                    }
                }
                return _idsFromSomething;
            }
        }
```

a solution may be to add an assertion to know when invalidate this variable like :

```
 public static object IdsFromSomethingLocker = new object();
            public static int[] IdsFromSomething
            {
                get
                {
                    if (_idsFromSomething == null || needToBeInvalidate)
                    {
                        lock (IdsFromSomethingLocker)
                        {
                            if (_idsFromSomething == null)
                            {                            
                               _idsFromSomething = // some long loading treatment
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return _idsFromSomething;
                }
            }
```

but I don't want to add a boolean for each similar treatment.

Is there a way to add a custom attribute above my "cached" properties to know when I need to invalidate them?

**edit :** for exemple the long treatment could be "load an xml file and parse it" but when my file is modified I want to invalidate my static properties, I don't want to use HttpCache(because I want a solution who could be use in a another context too (winForm). and the xml case can be another datasource In my case I retreive datas from RavenDB.

originals datas are updated by another program.

Comment: It comes down to what the condition is for invalidation, what it is, whether it is the same for all cached properties?

Comment: no it cannot be the same condition

Comment: Ok, so how is the condition determined, is it via a function call, for example?

Comment: You'll shoot yourself in a leg if you do this. Some code may get old objects, other - new ones. It's very hard to do it really thread-safe, and it's not about that particular code you shared, but about all other code which will use it. Refactor that code so that you won't need to do such things that will make your life easier in a future.

Comment: I will be curious to see how you implement singleton patern in C#, because according to msdn it is no so far that I'm doing (about thread safing) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx